# question about two different definitions of limit point

Tags: general-topology

From the definition of a limit point it follows  :

> A limit point $x$ of a subset $S$ of a topological space $X$ is a point such that **every** neighborhood of $y$ has a point in common with $S$.

also based on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point) :

> it doesn't make a difference if we restrict the condition to open neighborhoods only.

I know that if **every** neighborhood of $y$ intersects $S$, then also open neighborhoods of $y$ has a point in common with $H$

but why we can claim that if every **open** neighborhood of $y$ intersects $S$ then, so does **every** neighborhood of $y$?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a neighborhood of a point?

Comment: @PauloMourão, yes , a neighborhood of a point $s$ is a set  such that it contains another open set containing $s$

Comment: Precisely. That open set is an open neighborhood of the point. If every open neighborhood intersects $S$, then so does that one. So your neighborhood contains a set that intersects $S$, so it also intersects $S$. Does this make sense?

Comment: If it does not, I will write a more detailed answer.

Comment: @PauloMourão, I understand but cannot see which direction you are proving, can you please withe the proof in both directions?

Comment: What you're calling a "limit point" is often (and less confusingly) called "an adherence point". A limit point of $A$ is then a point $x$ such that every (open) neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$ *in a point different from* $x$. The set of all adherence points of $A$ is then denoted $\overline{A}$ and called the closure $A$, and it's easily shown $\overline{A}$ is the smallest closed set that contains $A$ as a subset. Points of $A$ can then be limit points of $A$ *or* isolated points of $A$, one or the other holds. They trivially are always adherence points of $A$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, can we take an  adherence point as a synonym for a limit point? also I always see that the definition of a limit point, accumulation point, cluster point are all the same, but the application of these words is a little different, for example I've seen that the words "accumulation point" or "cluster point" is used in a sequence or mostly in real analysis, although I don't know why these different words have been used by different mathematicians if they all have the same concept.

Comment: Most importantly, you have to be clear in what you mean when. If you want to use it as a synonym, fine, but make note of it. Define terms before use. Books also use accumulation point and cluster point, sometimes to mean the same notion sometimes different ones. Always check (a good text has an index of definitions IMHO)! Sometimes terms originate in different languages and people read certain papers that use terms in certain ways and they continue that usage. Tradition etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, by your question, you seem to have understood this direction but I will write it anyways: open neighborhoods are a special case of neighborhoods. So, if every neighborhood of $y$ intersects $S$, the same can be said for every open neighborhood.

Now, for the other direction, assume every open neighborhood of $y$ intersects $S$ and let $V$ be a neighborhood of $y$. By definition, $V$ contains an open set $U$ which contains $y$. $U$ is an open neighborhood of $y$, so $U$ intersects $S$. But $U\subset V$, so $V$ also intersects $S$. $V$ is an arbitrary neighborhood, so every neighborhood intersects $S$.

Comment: For completeness there is another point, which the OP ignored: the precise meaning of limit point. The old view (decades ago when I was an undergraduate) was that an isolated point of $S$ was a limit point of $S$. The modern view seems to be that the neighbourhood of $y$ has to contain a point of $S$ **other than itself** for it to qualify as a limit point.

Comment: @almagest,actually every limit point of $S$ of a topological space $X$ is an isolated point,but the other direction does not hold necessarily,for example consider the set of natural numbers ,any natural number $n$ is actually an isolated point,but you always can find a neighborhood of $n$ such that the neighborhood does not have a non-trivial intersection with the set of natural numbers,also the definition you've mentioned for neighborhood is indeed the definition of a limit point.

Comment: @almagest see my comment on the question too. limit point in the meaning of intersecting in another point is actually older and goes back to Sierpinski etc. It doesn't really matter which notion one uses, as long as one is clear.

Comment: @Absurd "every limit point is an isolated point" is nonsense...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes. I completely agree that it doesn't matter what notion one uses, so long as one is clear. Of course, it helps to be familiar with the conventions most people are following, but I agree that the overriding objective should be to be clear (and correct).

Answer (score -3):

Mathematicians often shorten the statement

> $U$ is an open set containing $x$

to the phrase

> $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$.

Borrowing from Munkres:

> If $A$ is a subset of the topological space $X$ and if $x$ is a point
>   of $X$, we say that $x$ is a ***limit point*** (or “cluster point”, or
>   “point of accumulation”) of $A$ if every neighborhood of $x$
>   intersects $A$ in some point *other than* $x$ *itself*. Said
>   differently, $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if it belongs to the closure
>   of $A − \{x\}$. The point $x$ may lie in $A$ or not; for this
>   definition it does not matter.

Comment: How exactly did you prove the equivalency between the two statements? the definition of a limit point is clear but the reason how an open neighborhood can be used instead of a "neighborhood" is not something that just exists because mathematician often shorten the statement.

Comment: I borrowed that part also from the same book: Topology, by J. Munkres, Pearson Education Limited 2014, page 96. On the next page, page 97, author added:
Some mathematicians use the term “neighborhood” differently. They say that A
is a neighborhood of x if A merely contains an open set containing x. We shall not follow this practice.